# How to solve, if possible a Selenium / Python code runing slow on each iteration?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I run this (part of) code:

```
while (True):
   try:
        time.sleep(5)
        start_time = time.time() 
        # Get the scrapped table data
        table_data = []
        rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
        for row in rows:
            row_data = []
            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
            for cell in cells:
                row_data.append(cell.text)
            table_data.append(row_data)
            print(row_data)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) 
###
# then saves to the database
# changes to a page with the next table and    
# return to while loop start
###
```

It works well on getting data, but only after some time do I notice that become slower on each iteration... doing some prints and counting time, I notice that only this part of the code becomes slower (1s more on each iteration), and other parts on this while loop don't change the execution time

I took account with code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759255/computing-time-on-each-iteration) and got this values (lines with start_time and print seconds....):

```
--- 9.43001103401184 seconds ---
--- 9.989665746688843 seconds ---
--- 10.980393886566162 seconds ---
--- 12.015849828720093 seconds ---
--- 13.079446077346802 seconds ---
--- 14.133357286453247 seconds ---
--- 15.820979833602905 seconds ---
--- 16.55774736404419 seconds ---
--- 19.471170663833618 seconds ---
--- 25.035650730133057 seconds ---
--- 27.544485092163086 seconds ---
--- 30.97364568710327 seconds ---
--- 30.9657781124115 seconds ---
--- 34.56339645385742 seconds ---
--- 35.829299211502075 seconds ---
```

- I guess there is something more (in memory) that I should clean up or change on this code to become more efficient. Maybe it could be some restrictions of the URL, but I can get the whole HTML at once without delays too.
- I checked memory on `taskmgr` and seems normal working, no increases, just higher activity of CPU when running, but normal level.
- I have run this code for more than 20 hours and it doesn't break. but become always slower, once, I measured more than 3 minutes to run this same piece of code that runs in less than 10s on the first time.

Some ideas on how to fix it or what's happening?

UPDATED
What I do related to Selenium, before the issued code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

nav = webdriver.Chrome()
nav.get("https://uri_from_where_i_get_test_data.com/page")
```

Comment: How is `table` defined? How is the data save to the db? The db is getting larger and larger during running of the script so it may become more time consuming to save data if you're using a relational db engine.

Comment: @NotAName as I told on question, table saving and database part is not related with this time count, and doesn't increase overall time. Problem happens only with this code part. What becomes slower is this Selenium process lines. When printed to console, after some time is visible that even printing becomes slower each time, (like getting each row is slower).

Comment: You should get more timing points to see where it actually gets slow. Maybe that will give indication as to which part of the loop is causing the slowdown.

Comment: You mean inside loop?
At process to record database I measured and stays always fixed in 3 seconds, between 3.02 to 3.08.

Comment: Even if the database operations are staying the same, we do not have enough information to answer your question. You basically need to profile each and every Selenium-related action to identify the part that gets slow. What about memory usage? CPU usage? Is the Python runtime generating an enormous amount of objects that cause the garbage collector to slow down?

Comment: I basically only calls selenium and webdrive to run (updated on question)
On taskmgr I don't see any changes in increasing memory or CPU usage.
About Python runtime, I'm not sure how to check this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there may be a direct problem with the server from which I'm scraping. We noticed some updates on the server, and after a few days, the execution time started fluctuating between 8 to 13 seconds, but it no longer consistently increases (although it still happens occasionally).

I even implemented a multithreading approach, and all threads are still performing well within the expected time.